# Use Windows.Networking.Sockets.MessageWebSocket on HoloLens with Unity to communicate with Socket.io

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, websocket, uwp, socket.io

I am trying to use the [simple sample MessageWebSocket code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/websockets#use-messagewebsocket-to-connect) in a simple Unity3D HoloLens project to build it on the HoloLens (UWP).

My Code is 1:1 the same as on the Microsofts page, except that I wrapp almost everything with `#if !UNITY_EDITOR
  ... #endif`

**What I want: A simple WebSocket Client, running on HoloLens communicating with socket.io!**

Code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
#if !UNITY_EDITOR
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows;
#endif

public class WebSocket : MonoBehaviour {
#if !UNITY_EDITOR
    private Windows.Networking.Sockets.MessageWebSocket messageWebSocket;
#endif

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        Debug.Log("WELCOME 2 THE UNITY");

#if !UNITY_EDITOR
        Debug.Log("WELCOME 2 THE HOLOOOO");
        startSocket();
#endif
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
#if !UNITY_EDITOR

    void startSocket()
    {

        this.messageWebSocket = new Windows.Networking.Sockets.MessageWebSocket();

        // In this example, we send/receive a string, so we need to set the MessageType to Utf8.
        this.messageWebSocket.Control.MessageType = Windows.Networking.Sockets.SocketMessageType.Utf8;

        this.messageWebSocket.MessageReceived += WebSocket_MessageReceived;
        this.messageWebSocket.Closed += WebSocket_Closed;

        try
        {
            Task connectTask = this.messageWebSocket.ConnectAsync(new Uri("wss://echo.websocket.org")).AsTask();
            connectTask.ContinueWith(_ => this.SendMessageUsingMessageWebSocketAsync("Hello, World!"));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Windows.Web.WebErrorStatus webErrorStatus = Windows.Networking.Sockets.WebSocketError.GetStatus(ex.GetBaseException().HResult);
            // Add additional code here to handle exceptions.
            Debug.Log(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private async Task SendMessageUsingMessageWebSocketAsync(string message)
    {
        using (var dataWriter = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataWriter(this.messageWebSocket.OutputStream))
        {
            dataWriter.WriteString(message);
            await dataWriter.StoreAsync();
            dataWriter.DetachStream();
        }
        Debug.Log("Sending message using MessageWebSocket: " + message);
    }

    private void WebSocket_MessageReceived(Windows.Networking.Sockets.MessageWebSocket sender, Windows.Networking.Sockets.MessageWebSocketMessageReceivedEventArgs args)
    {
        try
        {
            using (Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader dataReader = args.GetDataReader())
            {
                dataReader.UnicodeEncoding = Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8;
                string message = dataReader.ReadString(dataReader.UnconsumedBufferLength);
                Debug.Log("Message received from MessageWebSocket: " + message);
                this.messageWebSocket.Dispose();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Windows.Web.WebErrorStatus webErrorStatus = Windows.Networking.Sockets.WebSocketError.GetStatus(ex.GetBaseException().HResult);
            // Add additional code here to handle exceptions.
        }
    }

    private void WebSocket_Closed(Windows.Networking.Sockets.IWebSocket sender, Windows.Networking.Sockets.WebSocketClosedEventArgs args)
    {
        Debug.Log("WebSocket_Closed; Code: " + args.Code + ", Reason: \"" + args.Reason + "\"");
        // Add additional code here to handle the WebSocket being closed.
    }
#endif

}
```

When I use *wss://echo.websocket.org* then it works, but when I change it to my locally running Socket.io Server it doesn't send any messages or recieves it. I have no errors.

I tried with *ws://localhost:1337* or *http://localhost:1337* - no luck. And with socket.io you send a message with an event (like: io.emit('event','message'); ) but in this case it is only dataWriter.WriteString(message);

-Yes, the HoloLens and my Socket.io Server is running on the same network.
-Instead of localhost, also used IP address of the computer where socket.io is running

**How can I use Windows.Networking.Sockets.MessageWebSocket to communicate with socket.io?**

Comment: from the error "The type or namespace name 'Task' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" it seems as you forgot to import `Task`, which you are using in the code several times

Comment: @Ronin I updated the code.

Comment: FYI, the reference code he's using is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/websockets

Comment: "locally running Socket.io Server" 

Is the server running on the HoloLens device itself?

Comment: @Sunius no it is running on the computer: "*-Yes, the HoloLens and my Socket.io Server is running on the same network. -Instead of localhost, also used IP address of the computer where socket.io is running*"

Comment: Are the correct network capabilities enabled? Have you tried establishing a simple TCP connection? Perhaps your PC firewall is blocking the connection?

Comment: Any luck on this one? I'm having the same issue with windows universal project ...